# How to show a data properly with alignment?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a main report with 2 chart Pro (Bar) graph and 3 tables. When I run this report then it show only 2 graph and one table another remaining  two tables gets  hide.
When I click on First chart bar slice then it show a table below the chart. The same when I click on second chart bar slice then it show another table below second graph.but table is overlapping with chart. Due to that not able to show data properly. Is there any other way to show a data with proper alignment?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add two Report Groups, one for charts and another for tables.

To add Report Group click on the report name and right click on "Add Report Group" , then select "Group by the following expression" option and leave it blank.